# Hosting a dotnet core console application on Linux using Nginx

Tags: c#, .net, linux, nginx

I'm trying to host a C# console app in this case a telegrambot using nginx so it can run as a linux service or deamon from my laptop. I've tried to follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and also a very useful youtube video I found. But when I start the service and run a command to check the status it gives me the following message:

```
$ sudo systemctl status myapp2.service
● myapp2.service - myapp example
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapp2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) since Sat 2020-11-07 13:40:49 CST; 4s ago
    Process: 35260 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myapp2/U21711269BOT.dll (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 35260 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

it's not giving me a core dump or any other error message and I've tried to configure the default file for nginx and still gives me the same problem. If anyone knows of a way to solve this issue I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the contents of the /etc/systemd/system/myapp2.service file. Also does the app run if you run it normally without the service.

Comment: Is your app a asp.net service or a pure console app? eg. can you access it via a browser if it is running

Comment: Try to execute "journalctl -u myapp2.service" to see the logs.

Comment: @Trekco yes , the app runs if I use the dotnet command on console along with the dll path or if I run it on jetbrains rider , contents of myapp2.service :
[Unit]
Description=myapp example
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myapp2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myapp2/U21711269BOT.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: @Trekco it's a pure console app, but the only documentation or videos I found online are web apps using asp dot net